# Angle brackets in x86 Intel assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, ollydbg

I'm new to assembly and was reading a guide that presented an example of a pinball function taken from Ollydbg. I was trying to understand what most of the instructions do but the following line has me completely confused:

```
01017455  |. E8 249D0000    CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.??3@YAXPAX@Z>
```

What do angle brackets mean in this respect? and is there anything meaningful in the name of that function? The "JMP." in the name has confused as well - is it just part of the function name and should be ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a call to a statically linked `.LIB` in your file. On Windows, API/library calls are realized by calling a `JMP` instruction in a special section of the executable.

For example

```
CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.??3@YAXPAX@Z>
```

will do a `CALL` to the following instruction

```
JMP.&msvcrt.??3@YAXPAX@Z
```

The `CALL` pushes the return address to the stack and then jumps to the following `JMP` instruction in this section. This `JMP` will not modify the return address - so it's effectively like a direct `CALL`.

Simplified:

```
curEIP:
  CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.??3@YAXPAX@Z>     ; pushes (curEIP+insLen) to the stack and JMPs to (some virtual label named) `msvcrt.??3` in this section named above
  ...
msvcrt.??3:
  JMP YAXPAX@Z                        ; JMPs to `YAXPAX@Z` - address of the real function in the statically linked LIB in memory
  ...
; after the CALL completes...
```

...it returns to the return value address previously pushed to the stack (initial EIP+instructionLengthInBytes) to continue the execution.

> What do angle brackets mean in this respect?

They are just a convention of showing you the relevant data of the above scheme

> and is there anything meaningful in the name of that function?

Yes. See above. The name between the brackets is different from debugger to debugger.

> The "JMP." in the name has confused as well - is it just part of the function name and should be ignored?

The `<JMP...` simply incidcates, that the following chars/address are to be interpreted as a reference to the jump table for statically linked libraries in your executable (in the (above mentioned) special include section). Have a look in a PE-Explorer/Debugger to reenact that.

Answer (score 0):

The angle brackets is used for Windows API calls.

For example, if I used a function from Kernel32 library, it would call Kernel32 with the angel brackets.